# Make String from Sequence of Characters

Tags: string, clojure, state, sequence

This code does not work as I expected. Could you please explain why?

```
(defn make-str [s c]
    (let [my-str (ref s)]
    (dosync (alter my-str str c))))

(defn make-str-from-chars
    "make a string from a sequence of characters"
    ([chars] make-str-from-chars chars "")
    ([chars result]
        (if (== (count chars) 0) result
        (recur (drop 1 chars) (make-str result (take 1 chars))))))
```

Thank you!

Comment: I want (make-str-from-chars [\u \r \a \n \u \s]) return "uranus"

Comment: for the record try to avoid loop/recur as much as possible, 99% of the time you don't need it. try to think in terms of map/reduce/apply

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You pass a sequence with one character in it to your `make-str` function, not the character itself. Using `first` instead of `take` should give you the desired effect.

Also there is no need to use references. In effect your use of them is a gross misuse of them. You already use an accumulator in your function, so you can use `str` directly.

```
(defn make-str-from-chars
  "make a string from a sequence of characters"
  ([chars] (make-str-from-chars chars ""))
  ([chars result]
    (if (zero? (count chars))
      result
      (recur (drop 1 chars) (str result (first chars))))))
```

Of course `count` is not very nice in this case, because it always has to walk the whole sequence to figure out its length. So you traverse the input sequence several times unnecessarily. One normally uses `seq` to identify when a sequence is exhausted. We can also use `next` instead of `drop` to save some overhead of creating unnecessary sequence objects. Be sure to capture the return value of `seq` to avoid overhead of object creations later on. We do this in the `if-let`.

```
(defn make-str-from-chars
  "make a string from a sequence of characters"
  ([chars] (make-str-from-chars chars ""))
  ([chars result]
     (if-let [chars (seq chars)]
       (recur (next chars) (str result (first chars)))
       result)))
```

Functions like this, which just return the accumulator upon fully consuming its input, cry for `reduce`.

```
(defn make-str-from-chars
  "make a string from a sequence of characters"
  [chars]
  (reduce str "" chars))
```

This is already nice and short, but in this particular case we can do even a little better by using `apply`. Then `str` can use the underlying `StringBuilder` to its full power.

```
(defn make-str-from-chars
  "make a string from a sequence of characters"
  [chars]
  (apply str chars))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first and the second version of your answer (which use recursion) do not work. I still do not understand why recursion does not work.

Comment: @user477768, they do now, at if-let, statements were in the wrong order plus added parans around the fn calls.

Comment: @kotarak An example of an extremely clear and concise example that gradually progresses from a "way of doing it" to the "correct way to do it". Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 12):

This is very slow & incorrect way to create string from seq of characters. The main problem, that changes aren't propagated - ref creates new reference to existing string, but after it exits from function, reference is destroyed.

The correct way to do this is:

```
(apply str seq)
```

for example,

```
 user=> (apply str [\1 \2 \3 \4])
 "1234"
```

If you want to make it more effective, then you can use Java's StringBuilder to collect all data in string. (Strings in Java are also immutable)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn something more than just using APIs. Implementing something like this is a way of learning, I think.

Comment: Re: the final sentence: `str` already uses `StringBuilder` in its variadic case, as well as heavy type-hinting (especially in 1.3, which also makes it `:static`) and a `recur` for the loop building up the string in the `StringBuilder`. The only bit of extra logic in there is the special handling of `nil` (so that `(str nil)` returns `""`). It would be hard to improve upon this performance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use *clojure.string/join*, as follows:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str] )
(assert (= (vec "abcd")                [\a \b \c \d] ))
(assert (= (str/join  (vec "abcd"))    "abcd" ))
```

There is an alternate form of *clojure.string/join* which accepts a separator.  See:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/join