# Creating a string of blank characters

Tags: clojure

How would one construct a code that inserts b blank characters in between two input strings?
Concretely I am asking about a function which inputs

```
        (newfn "AAA" "ZZZ" 10)
```

and outputs 10 blanks between the strings "AAA" and "ZZZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn wrap-spaces [h t n]
  (let [blanks (apply str (repeat n " "))]
    (str h blanks t)))

(wrap-spaces "AAA" "ZZZ" 10)
```

Comment: [Relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304879/make-string-from-sequence-of-characters) Sorry I don't know how to link.